# Useragent automation is not working in cypress to test in mobile view. Tried viewport as well but failed

Tags: jquery, automation, cypress, viewport, user-agent

I am currently trying to automate a website for its mobile view using cypress. I tried using viewpoint but it seems that the site isn't responsive enough. *https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrHKA.png*  I used userAgent as well but it is not working. Here are some of the codes that I tried:

```
///<reference types = "Cypress"/>


describe("Test for mobile view", () => {
//method 1: using viewport
    beforeEach(() => {
       cy.viewport('iphone-x')
    })

// method 2: using useragent
    before(() => {
        cy.visit('https://www.bookmundi.com/', {
            onBeforeLoad: win => {
                Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'userAgent', {
                    value: 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
                });
            },
        });
    });
//method 3: using both useragent and viewport
    beforeEach(() => {
       Cypress.config('userAgent', "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1");
       cy.viewport('iphone-6')  // Set viewport to 375px x 667px
    });


    it("should be able to go to home page", () => {
//method 4: tried by keeping random size
        Cypress.config({
           viewportHeight: '375px',
           viewportWidth: '667px',
           userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36'
        })
        cy.visit("https://www.bookmundi.com/"); //homepage

//method 5:tried using headers
        cy.visit('https://www.bookmundi.com/', {
          headers: { 'user-agent': 'mobile' }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting userAgent in cypress.json config file.

```js
{
  "baseUrl": "https://www.bookmundi.com",
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1"
}
```

Test

```js
it('my test', () => {
  cy.viewport('iphone-x')
  cy.visit('/')
})
```

[brian-mann commented on 23 Aug 2018](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2100#issuecomment-415238103)

> You cannot change the user agent in the middle of a test. What you can do is split up the mobile tests from the desktop tests and then run those groups separately via a different `cypress run --config userAgent=...`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. However, I have one question. If you use the above code in cypress.json, you won't be able to use 
` "chromeWebSecurity": false `
for your test.

Comment: I'm not sure, is there a conflict between the settings? Would need something to assert in the test that would cause a fail if chromeWebSecurity could not be turned off.

Comment: I am testing to test for stripe payment but it needs chromeWebSecurity. The code works in desktop view but not in mobile view

Comment: Interesting, I will try out with stripe. Can you confirm you set `chromeWebSecurity: false` and the mobile test failed?

Comment: Also I see that `chromeWebSecurity` only works with chrome browser, but note the user agent is Safari - so maybe change that.

Comment: I have two cy.visit in my tests, first one is for authentication, second one is the test case. First cy.visit uses my userAgent config, but the second one is reverting back to my OS userAgent. do you guys have any idea, why? thx.

Comment: Based on what Brian Mann said it seems unlikely. Unless something changed in a more recent version.